# touchesBegan not firing in PDFView

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan, pdfview

I am trying to determine the location of a touch on a PDFView. I have set my pdf view to be user interacted as follows:

```
pdfView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

I then use the following function to detect touches:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: pdfView)
        print(position)
    }
}
```

The touchesBegan code is never fired.

Comment: Have you tried  overriding canBecomeFirstResponder and returning true?

Comment: No Leo, I will try that just now.

Comment: Still no luck Leo. I added self.pdfView?.becomeFirstResponder() to viewDidLoad() but still not firing touchesBegan.

Comment: thats not what I said. try adding this to your view controller `override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
`

Comment: No still not responding.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn’t find a solution.

Comment: anyone found solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Add gesture recognizer to PDFView like below:

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

     if var recognizer = pdfView.gestureRecognizers {
        recognizer.append(tapGesture)
        pdfView.gestureRecognizers = recognizer
    }
```